# Electron [28.1.3] - Not able to change application menu

Tags: electron

I currently have a simple Electron app - it compiles and starts up as expected. However, when I try and change the default menu at for the program, it wont take effect.

I am trying to set it to `null` just to make sure the app is updated, but it still shows the default menu.

```js
Menu.setApplicationMenu(null);
```

What am I doing wrong?

```js
import { app, BrowserWindow, screen, Menu } from 'electron';
import path from 'path';
import url from 'url';
import handleSquirrelEvent from './squirrel-app-setup'

if (require('electron-squirrel-startup')) app.quit();

let mainWindow: BrowserWindow | null;

function createWindow() {

    const { width, height } = screen.getPrimaryDisplay().workAreaSize;
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: width,
        height: height,
        icon: path.join(__dirname, 'assets', 'logo.ico'),
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true,
            contextIsolation: false
        }
    });

    const startUrl = process.env.ELECTRON_START_URL || url.format({
        pathname: path.join(__dirname, '/../dist/index.html'),
        protocol: 'file:',
        slashes: true
    });

    Menu.setApplicationMenu(null);

    mainWindow.loadURL(startUrl);

    mainWindow.on('closed', function () {
        mainWindow = null;
    });
}


function initApp() {
    if (handleSquirrelEvent(app)) {
        return;
    }

    app.on('ready', () => {
        createWindow();
        Menu.setApplicationMenu(null); // Set the application menu to null here
    });

    app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
        if (process.platform !== 'darwin') app.quit();
    });

    app.on('activate', function () {
        if (mainWindow === null) createWindow();
    });
}

initApp();
```

Comment: Could you please try with an older version of Electron and see if it works? It's it's a bug with the version then you should open an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues).